# Display checkbox values in email

Tags: php, email, checkbox

On this site [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/das-bauteam/kontakt.php) there are 4 checkboxes. At the moment the checkbox values are not shown in email.
What has to be done to get the checkbox values in the email?

This is the whole code [kontakt.php](http://pastebin.com/vvcbHNgc) [sendmail.class.php](http://pastebin.com/jTPp9xPF)

kontakt.php:

```
<form action="kontakt.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Ihr Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="get1" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>" />
    <br />
    <label for="phone">Telefonnummer (bitte nur Ziffern):</label>
    <input type="text" class="get1" name="phone" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']); ?>" />
    <br />
    <label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse:</label>
    <input type="text" class="get1" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>" />
    <br />
    <label for="message">Ihre Mitteilung an uns:</label>
    <textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']); ?></textarea>
    <br />
    <label>Welche Leistungen interessieren Sie besonders?</label>
    <label style="display:inline;" for="dachstuehle">Dachstühle</label>  
    <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="dachstuehle" value="dachstuehle" />
    <label style="display:inline;" for="holzbau">Holzbau</label>
    <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="holzbau" value="holzbau" />
    <label style="display:inline;" for="innenausbau">Innenausbau</label>
    <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="innenausbau" value="innenausbau" />
    <label style="display:inline;" for="trocken">Trockenbau</label>
    <input class="kaestchen" type="checkbox" name="interessen[]" id="trockenbau" value="trockenbau" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="Nachricht versenden" name="submit" />
</form>
```

sendmail.class.php:

```
<?php
class sendMail {
    var $to = 'email'; // set contact email
    var $name = '';
    var $phone = '';
    var $email = '';
    var $body = '';
    var $interessen = '';
    var $error = array();
    var $headers = array();

    function parseBody() {
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
        $message .= '<tr style="background-color: #eee;"><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>' . $this->name . '</td></tr>';
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Telefonnummer:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->phone . "</td>    </tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>E-Mail-Adresse:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->email . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Text:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->body . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Interessiert an:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->interessen . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";
        $this->body = $message;
    }

    function send() {
        if ($this->error) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (mail($this->to, '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $this->body, $this->headers)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->error[] = 'Fehler beim senden';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This is the whole code [kontakt.php](http://pastebin.com/vvcbHNgc) [sendmail.class.php](http://pastebin.com/jTPp9xPF)

Comment: How do you want them displayed in the email?? Comma Seperated?

Comment: interessen will be an array, looks like you're treating it as a string? And in your full class I don't see where you are setting that value.

Comment: In your `sendmail.class.php`, you do not retrieve `$_POST['interessen']`, which is an array. You will need to add that into the function that loads post values, and call `implode()` on it to return a string.

Comment: Note that if you have the opportunity to make the change, it is recommended to update your code to PHP5 style classes, rather than the old PHP4 style using the `var` keyword.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Ok I checked your sendmail class, and you need to do this in your setParams() method

Comment: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/das-bauteam/php/sendmail.class.php on line 20 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/das-bauteam/php/sendmail.class.php:20) in /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/das-bauteam/kontakt.php on line 11

Comment: I put the code here: function setParams($post)
 {
 
  $string = implode(", ",$this->interessen);
  if ( ! $this->name = strip_tags(trim($post['name'])))

Comment: No thats wrong....follow my code below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple...

So just put in your setParams() method like this.....

```
function setParams($post)
  {
  $this->interessen = implode(", ",$post['interessen']);
  //REST OF SETPARAMS STUFF...leave alone
 }
```

Then in your parseBody()...

Make sure the line that echoes the 'interessen'..is like this...

```
 $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Interessiert an:</strong> </td><td>". $this->interessen ."</td>
```

Which it is in your example above.

Comment: Just one question: where goes $string = implode(",",$this->interessen);? I'm not that advanced in PHP.

Comment: It gives me error message: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/das-bauteam/php/sendmail.class.php on line 53 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/das-bauteam/php/sendmail.class.php:53) in /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/das-bauteam/kontakt.php on line 11

Comment: Checked your sendmail class code, and you need to do this before the headers are sent....also its not being declared as a post variable....Ill provide code in a miinute

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Please upvote my question & give me your email so I can give you some tasks in future. I can pay you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31682/discussion-between-kylek-and-daniel-hernandez)